# Arguments of DetailView methods and usage of pk_url_kwarg

Tags: python, django

I'm currently watching a course on Django and wondering about the following code:

```
class RestaurantDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Restaurant.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        rest_id = self.kwargs.get('rest_id')
        obj = get_object_or_404(Restaurant, id=rest_id)
        return obj
```

1.) Why is the instructor of this course using `*args` in the `get_context_data` method but in the source code of django the `get_context_data` only has `**kwargs`

[Source Code of get_context_data method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L91)

2.) Furthermore the `get_object` method. Why does he use `*args` and `**kwargs` but the method in Django only has a `queryset` argument

[Source Code of get_object method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L20)

3.) And my last question, why isn't the just using the `pk_url_kwarg` variable to change the name of `pk` to `rest_id`

I rewrote this code an it still works but I'm really new to Django and I'm not sure if misunderstood something.

```
class RestaurantDetailView(DetailView):
    pk_url_kwarg = 'rest_id'
    queryset = Restaurant.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a Django user, `def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):` and `def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):` look unusual to me. The code will work because the same args and kwargs are passed to `super()`. You could argue that it makes the code more robust because it will still work if Django changes the signature in a future version. However I would prefer to use the same signatures as the parent class.

You are correct that you could use `pk_url_kwarg` instead of overriding `get_object`. The `pk_url_kwarg` should be the name of the kwarg in the URL pattern, so in this case it should be `pk_url_kwarg = 'rest_id'`. The advantage of `pk_url_kwarg` is that it simplifies the code. The disadvantage is that it's less obvious how the object is being fetched if you're not familiar with Django's class-based-views.

There's a couple more changes you could make. Instead of `queryset = Restaurant.objects.all()` you can simply set `model`, because `get_queryset` defaults to `self.model.objects.all()`.

Finally, the `get_context_data` method doesn't do anything apart from printing, so I would remove it entirely once I'd finished debugging.

Putting that together, you get:

```
class RestaurantDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Restaurant
    pk_url_kwarg = 'rest_id'
```