# Getting Object based on its ID

Tags: django, django-views

## Setup

I am trying to write a DeleteView that will delete an object based on its Id. The object is a journal and I want to reference the Journal that the user is currently located in. So for example if User1 is in Journal "Work" I want to delete that specific one based on journal Id and not anything else.

My understanding is that Django creates an ID fields (Autofield) for each model.

## Error

This is my current view:

```py
class DeleteJournal(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Journal
    tempalte_name = 'delete_journal.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        id = self.kwargs['id']
        return self.get_queryset().filter(id=id).get()
```

The error I receive is this:

[image]

What is the solution to this and why is it not working?

## EDIT 1

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', CreateToJournal.as_view(), name='to-journals'),
    path('<slug:slug>', ToJournalEntriesList.as_view(), name='to-journal-entries'),
    path('<slug:slug>/delete', DeleteJournal.as_view(), name='delete-journal'),
]
```

Please note, I do not want to delete based on slug, because a journal can have the same name and hence the same slug for different user. The only unique value is id, which is why I need to `get` id for the "current" journal.

Thanks a ton in advance, really appreciate anyone looking at this.

Comment: Please show the `path` object (or equivalent) for this view. It looks like that's the part which isn't set up correctly.

Comment: You don't need to define your own `get_object`, `DeleteView` already does everything you need, you just need to map an URL to your view, share your urls.py

Comment: @Jacinator I have added an update as per your request.

Comment: @bug I think I need get_object because default will be based of the slug, whereas I need id (or pk) specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, unfortunately the answer from Luis Silva did not help. I found out that the get_object() function requires a pk_url_kwarg set and after a little digging I found this StackOverflow post: [Arguments of DetailView methods and usage of pk_url_kwarg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939810/arguments-of-detailview-methods-and-usage-of-pk-url-kwarg#49939891).

This is the code for DeleteView:

**views.py**

```py
class DeleteJournal(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = to_journal
    tempalte_name = 'to_journals/delete_journal.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    pk_url_kwarg = 'id'
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to delete the object without the pk or id on slug you have to use the `get_object` method on your `DeleteView`

```
def get_object(self):
        return Journal.objects.get(pk=self.request.GET.get('pk'))
```

There's a similar question here:
[Django UpdateView without pk in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561736/django-updateview-without-pk-in-url)